# 'sep' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidytext

obtaining n-grams following this book on tydy-text: http://tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html

The code:

```
library(tidyr)

bigrams_separated <- austen_bigrams %>%
  separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ")

bigrams_filtered <- bigrams_separated %>%
  filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  filter(!word2 %in% stop_words$word)

# new bigram counts:
bigram_counts <- bigrams_filtered %>% 
  count(word1, word2, sort = TRUE)
```

I get an error:

```
Warning: Error in : 'sep' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'
```

Comment: I've checked the piece of code from the link along with the one you have pasted and everything works fine. I use: `R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)` Have you tried updating packages or `R` env?

Comment: Yes, updated packages and restarted Rstudio server

Comment: That is pretty weird; I can't reproduce it unfortunately. You said you are on an instance of RStudio Server. Do you know what versions you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code not loading tidyr:

```
bigrams_separated <- austen_bigrams %>%
mutate(word1 = sub(" .*", "", bigram),
       word2 = sub(".* ", "", bigram))
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an identical error, which seems to be solved by specifying tidyr::separate()